# 2 Divs and 2 Box Shadows

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap and am using a container-fluid with 2 full width divs and I'm trying to find out why I can see a box shadow on one, but not the other.  Here's what I have and I'm hoping someone can explain.  What happens right now is the 1st div has no box shadow and the 2nd div shows up with no issue.

```
.header-logo-bg { 
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(195,228,243,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */ 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(195,228,243,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */ 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(195,228,243,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */ 
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(195,228,243,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);     /* Opera 11.10+ */ 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(195,228,243,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */ 
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(195,228,243,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */ 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c3e4f3', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */ 
box-shadow: 0 4px 4px #aaa;
}
.header-bg { background: url('../img/diagonal-overlay.png') repeat #ebe0b1; padding: 30px; box-shadow: 0 8px 4px #aaa;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="header-logo-bg">
    <div class="inner">
        <!-- Logo here and some other stuff -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="header-bg">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphTitle" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/jEQ27/)

Comment: It looks like they both have box shadows to me ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEQ27/1/)). You just cannot see the top `<div>`s shadow very much because the bottom `<div>` is covering it up.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom `<div>` has a non-transparent background, and a higher `z-index`, so is just hovering over the other shadow and obscuring it. Try using a bottom margin on the top div to add some space.